# Finding elements that have certain descendent items

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to target navigation menu items that have sub menu items in order to put a down arrow after the items. So far I have this:

```
nav[role=navigation] ul li a:after { 
padding-left:5px; 
content: "\25BE";
color:#00b49c;
}
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

I have tried: `nav[role=navigation] > ul li a:after` but no luck.

Thanks folks

Comment: Can you show us a HTML snippet?

Comment: nav[role="navigation"] ul li a:after

Comment: Are you limited to CSS only? Or would you be open to jQuery? If the latter then jQuery has selectors such as `li:has(ul)` (selects all `li` tags which contain one or more `ul` tags). I will post a solution tomorrow for you to accept, if jQuery is ok.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy: I think you can post an answer. The OP acknowledges below that jQuery is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
nav[role=navigation] ul li a::after { 
content: "\25BE";
color:#00b49c;
display: block;
float: left;
width: 20px;
height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: This is not targeting list items that are parents - it targets all items, regardless of whether it has children.

Comment: Sorry, my bad: nav[role=navigation] > ul > li > a:after

Comment: I've just been told that sadly, CSS doesn't have any way of altering parent selectors based on children. Looks like jquery is the way to go. Thanks folks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, I am guessing that the ul is the sub-item, right? If that's the case, the best solution I can come up with (untested) is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("nav[role=navigation]:has(ul)").each(function() {
        $("ul li a", $(this)).after("\25BE").css({color: "#00b49c", paddingLeft: "5px"});
    });
});
```

Several things to note, if you're new to jQuery:

1. It is standard to use the `$(document).ready(function() {});` method.
2. The `:has` selector is specific to jQuery (as far as I know, although it may be included in CSS3 or 4 - whenever that comes out).
3. Note that the CSS properties in the `.css` function are comma separated, the property names miss out the dash where used and the first letter after the dash is capitalised (paddingLeft for example).
4. The `$(this)` after the `ul li a` is used to say any links within list items within unordered lists which are in the current object in the `.each` loop.

I am not entirely sure what it is you want to select - whether it is the nav, ul or li. Whichever it is, you should modify the above code so that the element you wish to select is before the : on the first line.

If I am not answering the question very well then please expand on what exactly you're trying to achieve and I will try my best to modify my answer to suit your requirements.